# Cannot convert multipolygon to polygon in shape file: no geometry column OGR_GEOMETRY?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, shapefile, ogr

The attempt is to change from multipolygon to polygon (shapefile) using:

```
ogrinfo tmpem122.shp -sql "alter table tmpem122 alter column OGR_GEOMETRY type geometry(polygon, 4326) using st_geometryn(geometry,1)"
```

I get this error message:

> ERROR 1: alter table tmpem122 alter column OGR_GEOMETRY type
> geometry(polygon, 4326) using st_geometryn(geometry,1) failed, no such
> field as `OGR_GEOMETRY'.

but according to `ogrinfo -sql "select * from tmpem122" tmpem122.shp`, the geometry column is `OGR_GEOMETRY` (or `_ogr_geometry_`):

```
Layer name: tmpem122
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 17
Extent: ...
...
...
Geometry Column = _ogr_geometry_
gid: String (10.0)
...
```

What would it be wrong? Please find the file sample here for your testing: https://file.io/U4XnvYSb69lp

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/407181/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PostgreSQL / PostGIS

Inside PostgreSQL this is the correct syntax to change the data type of a geometry column and fill it with the first geometry of a collection using `ST_GeometryN`:

```
ALTER TABLE tmpem122 ALTER COLUMN _ogr_geometry_ 
TYPE geometry(polygon, 4326) USING ST_GeometryN(_ogr_geometry_,1);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2800ce868fbd2fed399a49e078b61a1f)

### ogrinfo

Since you're only interested in modifying the existing geometry, you just need to modify the geometry instead of the column data type:

```
$ ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "UPDATE tmpem122 SET geometry = ST_GeometryN(geometry,1)" tmpem122.shp
```

- Using `-dialect sqlite` the geometry column is named `geometry`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it throws the same error message, weird that it works inside PostgreSQL. I am going to upload the file sample.

Comment: @Gery "The file you requested has been deleted" the file is gone

Comment: Thanks Jim for it, I re-uploaded it please find it here https://tmpfiles.org/dl/83316/tests.tar.gz.

Comment: @Gery now the link says "404 Not Found" :-D

Comment: @Gery see my last edit, I added a command that might do what you want

Comment: the last call did the trick, thanks a ton Jim!